# want to duplicate packets but netem only allows 100% is there another way to duplicate the packets?

Tags: networking

I am trying to test something and need my packets to be duplicated.
Netem only duplicates 100% at maximum but I need more than 100% duplicate at least 4-5 times more. Is there a way to do that?

i tried to do this

`tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root handle 1: netem duplicate 100`

`tc qdisc add dev ifb0 parent 1: handle 2: netem duplicate 100`

but it kicks me out after few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use that code on wan and another device like lan1. İm not sure but it should duplicate lan1 packets on lan1 and duplicate again 2 duplicated 2 packets on wan port. You want more? Try to use on bridge port too.